# Google Tv + SIP/VOIP (android.software.sip)

Tags: android, sip, google-tv

I am developing one "Client Ims-Sip" for Google Tv in android . To create this, it's necesary ->    SIP/VoIP (android.software.sip)

But I don't know if that feature is supported for "Google Tv 2.0"

Any one can help me?

If it is possible and any one know one tutorial or one page with good information?

Answer (score 2):

The android.software.sip feature is not supported on GoogleTV:
http://code.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_android_features.html

Comment: but in the last update to "HoneyComb 3.1", is equal ??
function is not yet supported??

Comment: I did not understand your question.